# ls: bash: printf: `Y': invalid format character in VS Code, not in Terminal

Tags: linux-mint, ls, date, visual-studio-code

I upgraded to Linux Mint 21 (based on Ubuntu 22), having number of small issues, one of which is in **VS Code**, not in Terminal (gnome-terminal), running **`ls` alias**:

> ```
> bash: printf: `Y': invalid format character
> ```

While I have defined these aliases:

```sh
# Base `ls` alias contains:
# - escape for it could be defined already
# - use colors when appropriate
# - group directories first
# - date format YYYY-Mmm-DD
alias ls="\ls --color=auto --group-directories-first --time-style=+'%Y-%b-%d'"
```

I did not notice this behavior in Focal, maybe I just look for errors now, or is this truly some error (mine, whoever)?

Notes:

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-conversion-specifiers.html

---

```sh
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `\ls --color=auto --group-directories-first --time-style=+'%Y-%b-%d''
ls is /usr/bin/ls
ls is /bin/ls
```

**Both** in Terminal and VS Code.

```
printf %q\\n "PS1=$PS1" "PS2=$PS2" "PS3=$PS3" "PS4=$PS4" "PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

```
PS1=\\\[\\e\]0\;\ \\w\ \\a\\\]\\\[\$color_green\\\]\\\$\ \\\[\$color_reset\\\]
PS2=\>\ 
PS3=
PS4=+\ 
PROMPT_COMMAND=
```

Only in VS Code (nothing in Terminal):

```
trap -p DEBUG
trap -- '__vsc_preexec_only "$_"' DEBUG
```

---

Image re-post from the original revision:

[image]

Comment: So it's not the prompt. Another related possibility would be a debug trap: what's the output of `trap -p DEBUG` ? And do you see the expected output from `ls` or not (actually, I think depending on the configuration the command might not be executed if the DEBUG trap fails, so that would still be consistent)?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' You just hit something, have no idea what it is though...

Comment: That vscode [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157226) was [fixed 2 days ago](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/5b23b086ffde3e3927db87186f56372e8fce7ff3), but that code is still very buggy. Looks like they need to read [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694) and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) at least).

Comment: and instead of fixing it to use `printf "... %s ..." "$__vsc_current_command"`, they've added a call to `sed` to escape the `%` signs. Sigh. Well, at least [someone has noted that in the bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157226#issuecomment-1207357558). (Also it doesn't look like `__vsc_preexec_only` uses the argument it gets anyway, hmm)

Comment: The initial version of this question included a screenshot (image) showing the error occurring.  While we dislike images of text, the correct remedy would be to transcribe the image as text into the body of the question, optionally adding more information *but not subtracting relevant information.*  The screenshot showed that you were getting normal `ls` output ***after*** the error message.  You should [edit] your question to restore that information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bash can process the text of the current command before running it by enabling the `DEBUG` [trap](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-trap). This was originally intended for debugging, but it is somewhat commonly used to set the window title to the text of the command while it's running.

The `extdebug` [bash option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) tweaks the way the `DEBUG` trap works. One of its effects is that if the code of the `DEBUG` trap returns a nonzero status, the command is not executed.

Your configuration in VSCode has a `DEBUG` trap set (`trap -p DEBUG` shows the code if set). This is very likely done to set the window title to the text of the running command. It appears that this code has a bug, and tries to pass the command in a `printf` format. This breaks when the command contains a backslash or a percent sign. Because the `extdebug` option is apparently enabled (I don't know why), the following command is not executed.

The solution is to either fix the buggy code, unset the trap (`trap - DEBUG`) or override the trap with other, non-buggy code (`trap 'other, non-buggy code' DEBUG`).

This is a bug in the `__vsc_preexec_only` function or another function that it calls. Thus, presumably, it's a bug in VSCode. As noted by Stéphane Chazelas, [that bug has already been reported](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157226) (and at the time of writing, there's a fix, but the fix is still buggy, it looks like the maintainers of that code don't understand what they're doing).

Comment: See the [vscode bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157226) actually [fixed 2 days ago](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/5b23b086ffde3e3927db87186f56372e8fce7ff3) (though that code is still very buggy. Looks like they need to read [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694) and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) at least and maybe realise that bash has builtin text substitution support and learn how to properly use `printf`).

Comment: The initial version of the OP's question had a screenshot showing that the `ls` command was run even after `printf` printed that error.